# How to generate 5- 20 Hz mechanical vibrations?

Tags: vibration, vibration-motor

My project deals with simulating a fixed frequency tremor and process it. The  required tremor range is 5-20Hz. I have been trying to generate this vibration motion with a vibration motor, but all i get is a frequency greater than 30Hz ( measured using accelerometer).

Is there any other way in which i can generate a 5-20Hz mechanical vibration?

OR Is there a way of reducing this frequency generated by the motor?

Comment: How about using an ordinary DC motor (like from an old cassette player) powered through a rheostat with a small off-centre weight attached to the shaft? Or, do you have a signal generator and a loudspeaker?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I am used DC motor with rheostat control, PWM control, voltage control, however, nothing seems to work.
How do you propose using loudspeaker and signal generator?

Comment: Check the output power capability of the signal generator. If it is suitable for driving a loudspeaker directly, do so. At a rough guess, a 10 cm diameter speaker would be enough for small amplitude vibrations. By "vibration motor," do you mean one of those tiny things used in mobile phones?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Yes. I have tried using the normal DC motors that we have as well as the ones used in mobile phones

Comment: You can get gear motors with relatively low gearing (3:1 or 4:1) that should run nicely at the speeds you,re interested in. These should be considerably more efficient than a loudspeaker at such low frequencies.

Comment: the motor i have is very small in size, smaller gears would be very difficult to find i think. Is there another way?

Comment: The frequency of vibration is directly related to the speed of rotation. Is it not possible to control this (very small)  motor's speed using PWM?

Comment: @JImDearden, I have already tried PWM control...speed decreases but not below 30Hz after which is stops. Also , 30Hz doesnt produce detectable vibrations.

Comment: You just need to get a different motor. 30 Hz (assuming a simple shaft offset) is 1800 rpm. Finding something slower than that should be fairly simple. However, if you're trying to control a DC motor with a rheostat, you should be aware that that is a pretty hopeless task. You need to buy a variable voltage source with the current needed for the motor.

Comment: Some cell phones have a haptic feedback device that is a small linear motor driving a mass side to side.  Not sure if the power is enough for you.  /  https://www.google.com/search?q=haptic+feedback+linear+motor&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how big the vibration  needs to be, or what your cost parameters are,  but I'll throw in with a [voice coil actuator](http://www.moticont.com/voice-coil-motor.htm?gclid=Cj0KEQjwwMi7BRDGptbvwOCDj8oBEiQAIALyDAAlNFUhNVGJ4sPL3NMqyUdIeyEG_qI0PAA9Ajm77WIaAh-E8P8HAQ)

[image: voice coil]

Comment: This is too epensive; my budget is not more than $15...

Comment: Wow. I was going to suggest a few things (using motors), but nothing would be in that price range.

Comment: Funny frequency point.  If you need great precise control in this range, these are a great way to go

Comment: Grab a speaker?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere -- for sure

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt with a vibration motor is a good start, but obviously you cannot control the vibration frequency precisely using an ordinary motor. You should try to mount and off-center weight on a stepper motor and control that. Note that most stepper motors can rarely go above [500-1000 RPM](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=75930.0). You need 1200 RPM, perhaps you'll find a motor which can do it. Otherwise you'll need a small gearbox to increase the weight's RPM.